# Angular 4 webpack tapable namespace has no exported member Plugin

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, node-modules

I get below error when I want to run test on my code `Angular4`, I've searched a lot but no luck, I get  stuck, any ideas would be appreciated. I got this error after installing `node_modules`

`node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:556:28: 
 Type 'typeof "/node_modules/@types/tapable/index"' is not a constructor function type.
Error at node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:598:46: Namespace '"/node_modules/@types/tapable/index"' has no exported member 'Plugin'.
Error at node_modules/@types/webpack/index.d.ts:602:53: Namespace '"/node_modules/@types/tapable/index"' has no exported member 'Plugin'.
    at Runner.run (\node_modules\tslint\lib\runner.js:92:27)`

this is my `package.json`:

`"@types/tapable": "1.0.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.16",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"`

Comment: this error only shows on running tests, but not in the dev server? Did you try `npm update`?

Comment: @ForestG yes just on running test, `npm` is the latest version

Comment: I think that @types/webpack is currently [1.4.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webpack), are you sure that that is updated too?